# Synthesizing an add with carry instruction

Tags: instructions, adc, easy68k

I was recently asked to use other instructions to synthesize an ADC(add with carry) instruction in the case that the processor did not have one. How would I go about this on a 68k machine?

Comment: This is not a realistic question because the 68k has an `ADDX` instruction for this purpose. All modern processors that have a carry bit will have an add-with-carry instruction. You should tell the person who asked you the question that it is unrealistic because the situation will never happen in practice. StackOverflow is for solving practical problems, not theoretical ones.